# The search function on Area 51 falls short of Ninja-quality

Tags: feature-request, area-51

**The search box is only available on the landing page,** so if you want to search from any other page, you have to go back there first.  It would be more accessible if it were always up in the header. (Maybe under the flying saucer?)

Also, **the search results are for the site-proposal, rather than the question in which your match exists.**  It'd be nice if it also showed the relevent question on the results page, but at a minimum, clicking a result should take you to the right page where the matching string is.  As it stands now, you go to the first page of the site proposal, then have to do an in-page browser search on each page to find the match.

I don't imagine this one to be high priority, but it'd slightly improve the UE, particularly as the site expands and the importance of searching increases.